# Expected value random variable- omega

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $\sigma$ algebra of Borel sets and $P$ - Lebesgue measure   on $\Omega$. Find: E(X|Y) while $X(\omega)=2\omega ,Y(\omega)=2\omega ^3$. I need some hints how to start this exercise.

Comment: Start by finding the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Okey and what next?

Comment: Well, what ARE the distributions of $X$ and $Y$? What is the definition of $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$?

Comment: I must find the combined density of X and Y but I know how to do this.

Comment: Note that $X$ is a function of $Y$, so...